# Mercurial - avoid whitespace changes

Tags: mercurial, codeblocks

Often when i modify some code and committing this. I end up with allot of (whitespace?) changes that doesn't really do anything, something like this :

```
--for( int i=0; i< 20; i++){

++for( int i=0; i< 20; i++){
```

This makes searching for modified files in later moments allot harder.

Currently, when I'm ready to commit changes. I tend to call :

```
hg diff -b > some_patch.patch   (the -b removes everyone of those uneeded changes)
```

I then apply, finish and amend the patch to get a good looking commit.
But this is getting cumbersome.

So either I need away to do this "-b" thing on a commit right away.
Or i need to stop my editor (codeblocks) from adding those useless changes.
Either way, i don't know how.

Some advice is appreciated. :)

Comment: If you want to automate your current process, you could wrap it into a pre-commit hook. That said, I just use a GUI tool to preview diffs and manually revert whitespace-only changes (and other gratuitous or irrelevant edits) before running the commit.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a `precommit` - or maybe server-side a `pretxnchangegroup` hook which checks the changes for coding style or sanity (e.g. also unwanted binary files or so)

[The wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HookExamples) has some examples for hooks, including a dummy-hook which could be extended to your needs. Alternatively, maybe the [CheckFiles](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CheckFilesExtension) extension is for you as it offers such check as part of the package.

However I suggest that you configure your editor such that it simply disallows trailing whitespace and trims that automatically (if you can't, get a better editor).